# Стеганографический метод встраивания информации

Tags: c#

Я написал метод стеганографии (LSB), который встраивает информацию в предварительно загруженный аудиофайл (WAV-файл) и на выходе получается новый аудиофайл со встроенным в него сообщением.
Помогите, пожалуйста, как изменить данный метод, чтобы было реализовано следующее:
Согласно методу, изменяется последний (восьмой) бит байта. Как сделать так, чтобы на форме пользователь, например, проставил checkBox "Изменить второй бит, изменить пятый бит, изменить седьмой бит" аудиофайла? И встраивание информации происходило бы уже согласно проставленным checkBox. 
Спасибо.

```
public void Hide(List<short> channelOneSrc, List<short> channelTwoSrc, List<short> channelOneDst,List<short> channelTwoDst, Stream messageStream)
    {

        byte[] waveBuffer = new byte[_bytesPerSample];
        byte message, bit, waveByte;
        //Получает следующий байт сообщения или -1
        int messageBuffer;


        while ((messageBuffer = messageStream.ReadByte()) >= 0)
        {
            //Присваиваем байт из буфера сообщения
            message = (byte)messageBuffer;

            //Записываем каждый бит взятого байта из сообщения в аудио поток
            for (int bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < 8; bitIndex++)
            {
                //Читаем один сэмпл из wav потока
                _sourceStream.Read(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length);
                //Запоминаем первые 20000 байт аудио файла в целях сокращения временных затрат на работу программы
                if (channelOneSrc.Count <= 10000)
                {
                    //Добавление значений байт аудио файла для дальнейшего их отображения в таблице замены бит
                    channelOneSrc.Add(waveBuffer[0]);
                    channelTwoSrc.Add(waveBuffer[1]);
                }

                //Изменяем бит только у одного канала аудио файла
                waveByte = waveBuffer[_bytesPerSample - 1];

                //Сначала делаем побайтовый сдвиг влево, а затем производим поразрядную операцию И 
                if ((message & (byte)(1 << bitIndex)) > 0)
                    bit = 1;
                else
                    bit = 0;

                //Изменяем последний бит байта аудио файла
                if ((bit == 1) && ((waveByte % 2) == 0))
                {
                    waveByte += 1;
                }
                else if ((bit == 0) && ((waveByte % 2) == 1))
                {
                    waveByte -= 1;
                }
                //Присваиваем новое значение байта
                waveBuffer[_bytesPerSample - 1] = waveByte;

                //Запоминаем первые 20000 байт аудио файла в целях сокращения временных затрат на работу программы
                if (channelOneDst.Count <= 10000)
                {
                    //Добавление значений байт аудио файла для дальнейшего их отображения в таблице замены бит
                    channelOneDst.Add(waveBuffer[0]);
                    channelTwoDst.Add(waveBuffer[1]);
                }

                //Записываем результат в целевой поток
                _destinationStream.Write(waveBuffer, 0, _bytesPerSample);
            }
        }

        //Записываем оставшуюся часть файла без изменений
        waveBuffer = new byte[_sourceStream.Length - _sourceStream.Position];
        _sourceStream.Read(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length);
        _destinationStream.Write(waveBuffer, 0, waveBuffer.Length);
    }
```

Comment: А вы точно сами это написали? Тогда скажите, а зачем вы проделываете эту операцию: "//Сначала делаем побайтовый сдвиг влево, а затем производим поразрядную операцию И " перед тем как перезаписываете последний бит?

Comment: Для того, чтобы выяснить, на что необходимо заменить (на 0 или 1) в исходном аудиофайле бит встраиваемого сообщения.
Если не прав - поправьте.